# Upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I have a laptop on which a friend installed Ubuntu 10.04, but I never really used it. Now I want to install the latest version and start using Ubuntu.

The update manager says that it is not supported at all. So, is it easier to uninstall Ubuntu 10.04 and then install 16.04.1 from scratch? I have no files of importance to save.

Any tips what is the best and quickest way of doing this? I am totally new to Ubuntu.

Comment: OSes don't need to be "uninstalled". Just install 16.04(.1) from scratch, either using the same partitions or, preferably, with the "Erase and install..." option. 10.04 is out of support for more than a year now.

Answer (score 5):

The best thing to get a properly working operating system in this case would be to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS right from scratch. Too many things changed in this long time frame since Ubuntu 10.04 was released. Many things may go wrong when doing an upgrade ... besides the fact that it would take much, much more time. Download [Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) and create an installation media, boot from it and select to use the whole disk from the installer, then start the installation process. This is the most easy way, in case you want to create new partitions yourself, choose 'Something else'.

Comment: I agree, a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS is the best alternative. Please remember to *backup* your personal files before :-)